# font changes css style on android chrome

Tags: css

i have this arabic font called `nazanin` it works fine but when i try it on a android chrome it changes the padding and etc.

this is how it shows on a regular browser

[image]

and this is how it shows on android chrome

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser has different default of css style. pc chrome and android chrome also.

maybe link reset.css or normalize.css could fix it.

https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

or

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

or...

if this "button" is button.

overwrite button style like below.

```
button{
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  etc...
}
```